# Using flow to get folder metadata

Tags: document-set, metadata, flow, reminder, power-automate

I'm using SharePoint to track assets, and each asset is configured as a "Document Set". This allows me to set properties for each set of documents at the Folder level, such as manufacturer, required calibration date, etc.

What I would like to do is use Power Automate to pull the calibration date from the Document Set (folder) metadata and compare it against today's date, and if the dates match to send an email notification to the user that the equipment must be calibrated.

I've found many tutorials on how to do this exact thing using lists in SharePoint, but am struggling to adapt it specifically to Document Sets.

Answer (score 0):

To get the metadata of a specific known Document Set, Power Automate **Flows** contain a `Get Folder Metadata` and a `Get Folder Metadata using path` as available actions.

If you need to look for Document Sets in bulk, you can use the `Get Files (Properties only)` action.  Despite the name of the action only having the word "Files", the action actually retrieves metadata for all **files and folders** in the specified library.  This action also allows an **OData Filter Query** to be passed as a parameter, so not only can you specify to return only DocumentSets (e.g. `ContentType eq 'Document Set'`), but you can also include your comparison criteria in the same filter (e.g. `CalibrationDate gt '@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}' and CalibrationDate lt '@{addDays(utcNow(), 1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}'`.

I have "guessed" at the internal name of your "Calibration Date" field, so make sure to use your actual field name, and if you have created a custom Document Set content type, you may have to replace the phrase "Document Set" in your OData filter with the actual name of your content type, but the following should get you all the document sets in your library that meet your criteria:
`ContentType eq 'Document Set' and CalibrationDate gt '@{formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}' and CalibrationDate lt '@{addDays(utcNow(), 1,'yyyy-MM-dd')}`